# LINQ Lambda where in subquery

Tags: sql, .net, linq

I´m trying do something like this :

```
Select * from A where id in (Select id_a from B)
```

But in LINQ

```
db.A().Join(db.B(), a => a.id, b => b.id_a, (a , b) => new { a, b}).....
```

I can do a JOIN. Is the best way? Or i have another options?.

*I´m using Entity Framework*

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think what you are doing is correct. Hope you are getting result you want

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? Do `db.A()` and `db.B()` return `IQueryable`?

Comment: Yes, i´m using EntityFramework and both return IQueryable. But didn´t work in the examples of below

Answer (score 1):

From my [SQL to LINQ recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245786/2557128):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`, using literal arrays or array variables for constant lists.
3. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.

So, for your SQL,

```
var id_aInB = from b in db.B select b.id_a;
var ans = from a in db.A where id_aInB.Contains(a.id) select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery in LINQ lambda

```
var q = db.A.Where(a=> db.B.Select(b=>b.id_a).toList().Contains(a.Id)).Select(a=>a);
```

Comment: Don't use `ToList` when using LINQ to SQL. Don't do worthless `Select(a => a)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Linq there are many ways to express that. That SQL can also be expressed in different ways and probably the best is to use an EXISTS query instead, like:

```
Select * from A 
where EXISTS (Select * from B where A.id = B.id_a)
```

That could be written in Linq as:

```
db.A.Where( a => db.B.Any( b => a.Id == b.Id_a ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```cs
var result=db.A.Select(c=>new {c,listId=db.B.Select(s=>s.id_a)}).Where(w=>w.listId.Contains( w.c.id)).Select(c=>c.c);
```

Or you can use LINQ like this

```cs
from a in db.A
let listId = from b in db.B
select b.id_a
where listId.Contains(a.id)
select a
```

By the way, use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/),you can get the right lamda by LINQ search